# How to Give Custom URL in the Order View Page in Admin Pannel

Tags: magento-1.9, url, custom

I have added the new button in the order view page in the back-end, Now i want to when i click on the button my custom URL "www.google.com" page will open in the new window.

I am using the below code:

```
$this->_addButton('order_reorder', array(
              'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Generate'),
              'onclick'   => "setLocation('".$this->getUrl('CUstome URL LINK')."')"

));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Magento `getUrl` methods are used for converting a route into a full URL including domain name. If you're attempting to link to another domain you do not need to pass it to `setUrl`. You can probably do something like:

```
$this->_addButton('order_reorder', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Generate'),
    'onclick'   => "window.open('http://www.google.com');",
));
```

Though I'm not sure you can reliably force open a new tab cross browser.